# re.findall(r'<span style="font-weight:bold">(.*?)<', string) if the element has a digit it does not return it

Tags: python

I have an expression to obtain all the elements that are under this structure:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">XXX</span>
```

but strangely in this case it does not return the correct result, I think it is because the first result is a single digit. in other cases it works perfect.

```
string="<td style="font-style:italic;font-size:90%">categoría&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold"> Q</span></td><td style="font-style:italic;font-size:90%">lema&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold"> MUY </span></td></tr>"

array= re.findall(r'<span style="font-weight:bold">(.*?)<', string)
print(array)

['MUY']
```

Should be

```
['Q', 'MUY']
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Your code is actually working for me](https://rextester.com/XZUR36882), at least with just a few minor changes.  _But_, you should avoid parsing HTML using regex, because it's evil.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what changes?

Comment: I gave you a demo link, and this is as much as I will do here.

Comment: It does work for me too. I just changed the double quotes to single quotes on `string='<td style="font-style:italic;font-size:90%">categoría&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold"> Q</span></td><td style="font-style:italic;font-size:90%">lema&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold"> MUY </span></td></tr>'`

Comment: its working perfectly
     `import re
     string = '<td style="font-style:italic;font-size:90%">categoría&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold"> Q</span></td><td style="font-style:italic;font-size:90%">lema&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold"> MUY </span></td></tr>'

   array= re.findall(r'<span style="font-weight:bold">(.*?)<', string)
  print(array) ` Output: [' Q', ' MUY ']